# How can I fix Hangfire configuration error?

Tags: c#, hangfire

It seems like I need to configure for logging. I can add jobs & see them in /hangfire page but they won't fire if I disable app.UseHangfireServer().

Since it's a simple folder based web site, I've copied necessary dlls to my bin folder from running sample Hangfire MVC project. How can I configure the logger if any required?

```
Error location:

Line 17:         {
Line 18:             app.UseHangfireServer();
Line 19:             app.UseHangfireDashboard();
Line 20: 

Source File: f:\hangfire\App_Code\Startup.cs    Line: 18
```

Stack trace:

```
[ConfigurationErrorsException: The configuration section for Logging cannot be found in the configuration source.]
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolderCustomFactory.ValidateLoggingSettings(LoggingSettings loggingSettings) +64
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolderCustomFactory.CreateObject(IBuilderContext context, String name, IConfigurationSource configurationSource, ConfigurationReflectionCache reflectionCache) +49
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterCustomFactory.CreateObject(IBuilderContext context, String name, IConfigurationSource configurationSource, ConfigurationReflectionCache reflectionCache) +66
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.ConfiguredObjectStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type t, Object existing, String id) +83
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild) +59
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.SingletonStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild) +169
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String idToBuild) +59
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.ConfigurationNameMappingStrategy.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context, Type t, Object existing, String id) +102
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.DoBuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies) +217
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, Type typeToBuild, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies) +127
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.BuilderBase`1.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, String idToBuild, Object existing, PolicyList[] transientPolicies) +87
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, IConfigurationSource configurationSource) +135
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp(IConfigurationSource configurationSource) +53
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterFactory.Create() +29
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.get_Writer() +106
   lambda_method(Closure , String , TraceEventType ) +252
   Hangfire.Logging.LogProviders.EntLibLogger.Log(LogLevel logLevel, Func`1 messageFunc, Exception exception) +60
   Hangfire.Logging.LoggerExecutionWrapper.Log(LogLevel logLevel, Func`1 messageFunc, Exception exception) +87
   Hangfire.Logging.LogExtensions.IsInfoEnabled(ILog logger) +42
   Hangfire.Logging.LogExtensions.Info(ILog logger, String message) +27
   Hangfire.BackgroundJobServer..ctor(BackgroundJobServerOptions options, JobStorage storage, IEnumerable`1 additionalProcesses) +236
   Hangfire.AppBuilderExtensions.UseHangfireServer(IAppBuilder builder, JobStorage storage, BackgroundJobServerOptions options, IBackgroundProcess[] additionalProcesses) +90
   Hangfire.AppBuilderExtensions.UseHangfireServer(IAppBuilder builder, BackgroundJobServerOptions options, JobStorage storage) +42
   Hangfire.AppBuilderExtensions.UseHangfireServer(IAppBuilder builder, BackgroundJobServerOptions options) +35
   Hangfire.AppBuilderExtensions.UseHangfireServer(IAppBuilder builder) +46
   MyWebApplication.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in f:\hangfire\App_Code\Startup.cs:18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got two startup points:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyWebApplication.Startup))]
```

and

```
[ApplicationStartup]
```

Removing [ApplicationStartup] and movind the Hangfire related code into other place fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Elmah (which Hangfire detects automatically in the newer versions).

But if you want to shut it off, setting the log provider to null should do the trick (You'd put this in the Start-up method of your app, which will be differ depending upon what mechanism you're using to perform the start up)

```
LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(null);
```

Source: https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/turn-off-logging/1150

Comment: It didn't help. The code has executed and I've received the same configuration not found error.

Comment: What version of hangfire are you using, and what does your initialization code look like?  I just tried to re-create your issue in a brand new project (just installed hangfire, started a background server, nothing in the configuration for logging), and it runs without any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Do You have any of logger library applied on Your solution? As Hangfire documentation says:

> Starting from Hangfire 1.3.0, you are not required to do anything, if
>   your application already uses one of the following libraries through
>   the reflection (so that Hangfire itself does not depend on any of
>   them). Logging implementation is automatically chosen by checking for
>   the presence of corresponding types in the order shown below.
>
> Serilog 
>   NLog 
>   Log4Net 
>   EntLib 
>   Logging Loupe 
>   Elmah 
>   If you want to log
>   Hangfire events and have no logging library installed, please choose
>   one of the above and refer to its documentation

So as I understand You need some of logging library listed above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a log provider. As a sample you can add an in build provider like so :

**LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new ColouredConsoleLogProvider());**

and it should resolve the error.